# Question about convergence of a sum of integrals as mesh tends to $0$ using continuity

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Below is a proof on approximating stochastic integrals for mean-square continuous processes in René Schilling's Brownian Motion.

My question is: How do we get the last convergence to $0$ in the proof? I.e. why is

$$\sum_{j=1}^n \int_{s_{j-1}}^{s_j} \sup_{u,v \in [s_{j-1},s_j]} E[|f(u)-f(v)|^2] dt \to 0$$ given that we have $\lim_{s \to t} E[|f(s,\cdot)-f(t,\cdot)|^2 ] = 0$ for each $t \in T$?

I am confused because the assumption only gives continuity at a point, i.e. $\lim_{n \to \infty} E|f(s_n)-f(s)|^2=0$ as $s_n \to s$. How do we get $\sup_{u,v\in[s_{j-1},s_j]} E[|f(u)-f(v)|^2] \to 0$ as $|\Pi| \to 0$?

Also from this we have $\sum_{j=1}^n \int_{s_{j-1}}^{s_j} \sup_{[s_{j-1},s_j]}E|f(u)-f(v)|^2 dt$ of the form $\sum_j (s_j - s_{j-1}) g_j$ where $g_j \to 0$ as $|\Pi| \to 0$. So we could bound this by $|\Pi| \sum_{j=1}^n g_j$, but we how do we get the sum tend to $0$ when each $g_j$ does? I would greatly appreciate any help resolving these issues.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mimic any proof that a continuous function on a closed interval is uniformly continuous, to show that given $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $|s-t|<\delta \Rightarrow \mathbb E[|f(s)-f(t)|^2] < \epsilon$.

(An example of such a proof: suppose for some $\epsilon>0$ there is no such $\delta$>0.  Find a sequences $(s_n, t_n) \in [0,T]^2$ with $|s_n - t_n| \to 0$ and $\mathbb E[|f(s_n)-f(t_n)|^2] > \epsilon$.  Let $(s,t)$ be a cluster point of $\{(s_n,t_n)\}$.  So $s = t$.  Since $\mathbb E[|f(s_n)-f(s)|^2] \to 0$ and $\mathbb E[|f(t_n)-f(t)|^2] \to 0$, it must be that $\mathbb E[|f(s_n)-f(t_n)|^2] \to 0$, which is a contradiction.)

So, if $|\Pi| < \delta$, then
$$ \sum_{j=1}^n \int_{s_{j-1}}^{s_j} \sup_{u,v\in[s_{j-1},s_j]} \mathbb E[|f(u)-f(v)|^2] \, dt \le \sum_{j=1}^n \int_{s_{j-1}}^{s_j} \epsilon \, dt = \epsilon.$$

Comment: I have one additional question: Why does this argument work even if we assume that it is discontinuous at finitely many points?

Comment: @nomadicmathematician If the function has a left and right limit at each point of discontinuity, then you just apply the result over each interval upon which it is continuous.  But if the the left and right limits don't exist, I don't see why the result should still hold.

Comment: The situation I look at has both limits. How do we deal with the supremum at these jumps?

Comment: The contribution from the discontinuities is at most $n |\Pi| L$, where $n$ is the number of discontinuities, and $L$ is an upper bound on $\mathbb E[|f(s)-f(t)|^2]$.

Comment: So we need both limits to have a uniform bound for the jumps.

Comment: Yes, but if the left and right limits exist, you will have such bounds.

Comment: And actually, the left and right limits aren't required.  Just the uniform bounds.